# Matlab: Randomize and Split

Tags: matlab, matrix, split

I have following data matrix in Matlab, I am trying to actually split this into multiple segments by passing a variable to a matlab function. But before splitting I would like to shuffle the matrix. The size of my matrix is `150X4`

```
s.data
5.1000    3.5000    1.4000    0.2000
4.9000    3.0000    1.4000    0.2000
4.7000    3.2000    1.3000    0.2000
4.6000    3.1000    1.5000    0.2000
5.0000    3.6000    1.4000    0.2000
..

s = 

  data: [150x4 double]
labels: [150x1 double]
```

Coming from R environment I find MatLab is very strange. Initially I thought the columns in matrix has a relationshop like in a R dataframe but thats wrong in my assumption.

Comment: What do you mean by `randomize`?  Get a bunch of random values?  Put the rows in a random order?

Comment: Sorry what I ment is something like a card shuffling scenario.. let me update that in the question

Comment: Do you also want to know how to split your matrix?

Comment: yes that would be fantastic, what I really want to do is given this s.data shuffle it and split to 10 chunks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or you can do:

```
 perm=randperm(numel(data)); % generate a random permutation
 data = reshape(data(perm),size(data)); % apply it to data
```

Comment: can you explain what data is here..?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis `data` would be the equivalent of `s.data` in your example above.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_data=data(randsample(1:length(data),length(data)),:)
```

Comment: It would be great if you can put some explanation.

Comment: My answer is different than @Oli's.  His answer keeps the elements of the matrix and randomizes their location anywhere in the new matrix, whereas mine shuffles the matrix, keeping the rows intact.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the shuffle answers, in order to split your data into matrices of `15x2` each, you can use `mat2cell`:

```
data = rand(150,4);        %# generates a random 150x4 matrix
rowdiv = repmat(15,1,10);  %# size of each chunk in rows. Must sum to 150
coldiv = repmat(2,1,2);    %# size of each chunk in cols. Must sum to 4
datacell = mat2cell(data, rowdiv, coldiv)
```

It will return a cell with 20 matrices, which are accessed by `datacell{x,y}`:

```
datacell = 

    [15x2 double]    [15x2 double]
    [15x2 double]    [15x2 double]
    [15x2 double]    [15x2 double]
    [15x2 double]    [15x2 double]
    [15x2 double]    [15x2 double]
    [15x2 double]    [15x2 double]
    [15x2 double]    [15x2 double]
    [15x2 double]    [15x2 double]
    [15x2 double]    [15x2 double]
    [15x2 double]    [15x2 double]
```

`B = repmat(A,M,N)` creates a large matrix `B` consisting of an M-by-N tiling of copies of `A`. We are using it here to generate an exact division of the rows and columns, repeating element `15` ten times and `2` twice, respectively. But, you don't need to do an exact division. You can set chunks with different sizes. Row with different size:

```
rowdiv =

    15    15    15    15    15    15    15    15    16    14
```

Will return:

```
datacell = 

    [15x4 double]
    [15x4 double]
    [15x4 double]
    [15x4 double]
    [15x4 double]
    [15x4 double]
    [15x4 double]
    [15x4 double]
    [16x4 double]
    [14x4 double]
```